# How to block bad url path that is not part of my site from showing in google search?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, node.js, ufw, robots.txt

I have got a site that is running on Node.js (Express) , and Apache httpd.

Hundreds of requests are coming in from malicious IP's, which I'm proactively blocking. (I have a script that looks at the logs, and if it sees malicious terms, it blocks the IP via a firewall(UFW).

However since it's getting a lot of hits, when I go to google.com, and type the name of my site, some of the results are something like:

https://site-name.com/bad-word-bad-word

Even though my site does not contain those bad words, it shows as a result on google, since those malicious IPs hits my site with those words.

Could someone please share some light and let me know how I could fix this? I have just created a robots.txt file and I'm now blocking bad bots from scanning the site also.

Much appreciated

Comment: You have cause and effect reversed: Malicious bots are hitting that URL because it is in Google search. You need to figure out why that URL ever answered anything other than a 404. A bug in your application maybe? Or your server was compromised?

Comment: Problem solved, I was returning 403 instead of 404, bad mistake. Thanks again.